# When should I encrypt my config file?

Tags: c#, encryption, app-config

I have a C# application that comes with an app.config file. The application is built on a build server and deployed to multiple users.
I'd like to encrypt the app.config, but I'm not sure about when to do so: If I do it straight after the build, won't the encryption depend on the build server credentials? How can the application decrypt on other machines? If I do the encryption on the users machine, won't this leave time when the app.config is unprotected?

Thanks

Edit:
I was considering using [DPAPI](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/04/13/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file.aspx). It uses the user's credentials to encrypt and decrypt. This is why I think I might have a problem delivering an encrypted file to the users.

Comment: You should *not* bother encrypting a file when you are also delivering the means to decrypt it to the same users. sounds like you need to implement a service somewhere here, to keep code out of "evil" hands.

Comment: Sensible information that need encryption should not go into the config file

Comment: But shouldn't the connection string go there?

Comment: Your connection string should not contain a password if you can use integrated security, in that case, i see no point in encrypting it, because all it contains is a server and db name. If it does contain a password, it makes sense to encrypt it.

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9408850/706456). It is possible to do this with RSA public-private key.encryption.

Comment: @Noich if you are putting sensitive info in a config file, you should *not* be delivering that file to untrusted users. Encrypted or not... they *will* have access to your login credentials. You need to use a service that handles login separately, or base logins on their own credentials.

Comment: @oleksii that solution merely pushes the encryption back one level. Once they find the key, game over. In my opinion, it's not worth doing. (non-sophisticated users won't be poking in app.config; sophisticated ones can follow the rabbit hole down whereever it goes.)

Comment: I should note that by "service", you shouldn't misunderstand it as e.g. a Windows service. @AndrewBarber is referring to a *remote* service (i.e. online), out of the reach of the user through unauthorized means.

Comment: @Mehrdad ooh, yes; excellent bit of information to add!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just read the addition to your post, and I don't think you actually need encryption at all...

You say that you intended to use a system that would encrypt/decrypt based on the user's credentials. That means two things:

1. You don't encrypt during build; you *can't* use this sort of system during build, for the reasons yoy noted.
2. You seem to be OK with the users having access to the data. In that case, you should not be using configuration at all, but you should be prompting them for login info (perhaps saving it securely afterward to reuse) or just using their Windows/domain logins.

Either way, you don't need to encrypt the file to protect it... you simply need to store the login info, or other config info, as *user settings*, rather than configuration, which is readable to all users.

Comment: From what I've been reading, encrypting the connection string is common practice, shouldn't it be?
I also plan to store multiple connection strings there, I don't want users to edit them.

Comment: it is often a pointless practice. don't do it if you are trying to hide the info from your users. because it only hides it from those who won't care to look anyway. as for keeping them from editing it... ummm... encrypting does *nothing* toward that goal. Nothing at all. Proper file permission do, though. (normal users should *not* have write permissions in the program's installation directory.